80's or early 90's futuristic/apocalyptic movie where girl doesn't know she is an android
I think it must be an 80's or early 90's film. I saw it on TV once or twice but never caught the name.
All I remember is: It's set in a futuristic post apocalyptic setting.
There's a girl about 20ish who at the start of the film is a prostitute and is having sex with several guys, and tells one of them he needs a condom, so one of the other guys pulls off his condom with a snap and says something like "You can use my skin brother".
Before or after this there's a scene in what is probably a dark bar, and a soldier/mercenary is looking for this girl, because she is actually a robot but doesn't know it. Also the girl has some information that the solider needs to get from her. I'm pretty sure he shoots someone in the bar with a bow and arrow.
I feel like maybe there is a disabled kid who the girl is prostituting to get money for, but I'm not sure about that.
Seriously any help appreciated. I can't find anything on google.

It's a live action movie? Or some kind of anime?

This appears to be the 1992 sci-fi film Prototype X29A. It's post-apocalyptic and has a female lead who doesn't know she's a cybernetic human, a disabled young man, a character who uses a bow and arrow, and (as specified by an IMDb review) contains this scene:

It even got borderline nasty at times, too, with one scene where our female lead is either prostituting to or about to be raped by four guys. The first assailant says to another, "USE MAH SKIN" and pulls off his used condom...

Here's the trailer; the entire movie is also available on Hulu here. A fair warning, though: This film has a Kato Kaelin cameo! 
